# Redirect Wordpress site to a landing (construction) page using htaccess, with access to /wp-admin and /invoice

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried everything I know and I can't seem to come up with a solution. I am trying to redirect my website to a landing page (which I have put into a folder with a css file, changing the index.html to index.php.

I have successfully redirected the website, but unfortunately no matter what I do, wp-admin redirects to the landing page as well.

There is another folder I would like to remain without being redirected as well. I presume once I understand how to exclude wp-admin from the redirect, I will be able to add other exceptions as well?

Here is what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/construction-landing/(.)*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /construction-landing/index.php [R=302,L]
```

Thank you in advance for your help!
Jules

Answer (score 0):

This may not be completely WordPress related.

But you may try a few suggestions mentioned on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414015/redirect-site-with-htaccess-but-exclude-one-folder).

Comment: Hi Andrius, thank you for your response. I've tried all the solutions on all the threads I could find, and nothing seems to work. I also posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57246895/10078060 and I haven't received a response. Do you have a suggestion of a better place to post? Thank you again. I really appreciate your response!